# CSV write string instead of col

Tags: python, csv

Have for example three lists:

```
list4 = (start_time, 'Test type1', 'Result1', 'Units1')
list5 = (start_time, 'Test type2', 'Result2', 'Units2')
list6 = (start_time, 'Test type3', 'Result3', 'Units3')
```

And then - they used in:

```
report = open('111.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(report, delimiter=';')

#writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=';')

for row in zip(list4, list5, list6):
   writer.writerow(row)
```

And this leads to this result:

```
$ cat 111.csv
2014-10-01 16:53:29;2014-10-01 16:53:29;2014-10-01 16:53:29
Test type1;Test type2;Test type3
Result1;Result2;Result3
Units1;Units2;Units3
```

But _ want - it create file like:

```
2014-10-01 16:51:21;Test type1;Result1;Units1;
2014-10-01 16:51:21;Test type2;Result2;Units2;
2014-10-01 16:51:21;Test type3;Result3;Units3;
```

Comment: Seems like you want to transpose your data. So instead of `zip(list4, list5, list6)` just `(list4, list5, list6)` without zip?

Comment: OMG! :-) Could you add you comment as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to transpose your data. So instead of `zip(list4, list5, list6)` just use `(list4, list5, list6)` or `[list4, list5, list6]`:

```
>>> zip(list4,list5,list6)
[(1, 1, 1), ('Test type1', 'Test type2', 'Test type3'), ('Result1', 'Result2', 'Result3'), ('Units1', 'Units2', 'Units3')]
```

but

```
>>> [list4,list5,list6]
[(1, 'Test type1', 'Result1', 'Units1'), (1, 'Test type2', 'Result2', 'Units2'), (1, 'Test type3', 'Result3', 'Units3')]
```

Answer (score 1):

you seem to be confused between tuples and list in python. any way second pythonic approach would be to append available tuples into a blank list. This way you could dynamically manipulate available data for csv writing instead of hard coding it:

```
csv_data = []
a = (start_time, 'Test type1', 'Result1', 'Units1')
b = (start_time, 'Test type2', 'Result2', 'Units2')
c = (start_time, 'Test type3', 'Result3', 'Units3')

if len(a)==4 :#eg condition: check if a has 4 elements
    csv_data.append(a)

#some other condition
csv_data.append(b)

#check if start_time is 1 day ago
csv_data.append(c)
#manipulated csv data is available in list csv_data
print csv_data
```